# Gnuplot issue? Contours connecting in a strange way

Tags: gnuplot, contour

I'm quite new to gnuplot and I'm using this code;

```
set xlabel 'x';
set ylabel 'y';

set palette rgbformulae 7,5,15;
set surface;
set cntrparam levels 10;
set isosamples 50;
unset key;

set title 'Magnetic Field Component, By';
splot 'ByF.txt' w l palette title 'By';
```

My issue is it comes out looking like this;

[image: 1]

It looks strange because it's adding contours or lines from y = 0 to y = 2 at z = 0 for all values of x. How do I stop it doing this? I have another plot using a different .txt file, inside these text files is basically this graph but rotated 90 degrees in the x-y plane which DOESN'T give me this weird z = 0 plane of lines. So it must be some setting of the contours which is going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably due to the fact that the data-file should leave one blank line between each x (or y) scan (called block in gnuplot)